# Rails using wrong id in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view, I have a table of users, and for each user, I have added a dropdown to set the role of that user.

```
<% smart_listing.collection.each do |user| %>
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= user.role %>

      <%= simple_form_for user, url: edit_user_role_admin_user_path(user), html: { id: 'edit-role' }, method: :patch do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :role,
          required: false,
          label_html: { class: 'sr-only' },
          label: 'Role',
          selected: user.role,
          input_html: { onchange: "$('#edit-role').submit();" }
        %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I have defined a custom action in the controller and set the routes.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users do
    member do
      patch 'edit_user_role'
    end
  end
end
```

The only problem is that the wrong id gets passed to the controller. The id is always set to 1, not to `user.id`.

Using a different id in the url, e.g., `url: edit_user_role_admin_user_path(2)`, works.

What is going on with the `user` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the same ID for for all your forms and then using it to hook your javascript handler.

When the browser encounters multiple elements with the same ID the query will usually return the first element.

Fortunately its pretty easy to clean it up:

```
<%= simple_form_for user, url: edit_user_role_admin_user_path(user), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :role,
   required: false,
   label_html: { class: 'sr-only' },
   label: 'Role',
   selected: user.role,
   class: 'instant-submit'
  %>
<% end %>
```

If you are using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) you would do it like so:

```
// application.js
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  $('form').on('.instant-submit', 'change', function(){
    $(this).submit();
  });
});
```

If not:

```
// application.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('.instant-submit', 'change', function() {
    $(this).submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there even is a standard behavior when multiple elements have the same ID. Anyways it is invalid HTML and should be avoided.

Comment: Good catch! I was copying code from another file and forgot about that. Using `input_html: { onchange: 'this.form.submit();' }` works, but I would like to make the JavaScript unobtrusive. But I was unable to get your JavaScript working. Nothing happens at all. I also tried putting the JavaScript in the view and adding `input_html: { class: 'instant-submit' }`, but that had no effect.

Comment: The following seems to work:

    $('.instant-submit').change(function() {
      $(this).submit();
    });

Comment: Ah the class was applied to the input itself. Glad that it worked out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `"$('#edit-role').submit();"`

Because your HTML page will have multiple `<form id="edit_role">` elements, your javascript will basically be sending the first form, which I presume to have the `user.id` of `1`.

To fix it, you'll be better calling the parent form... and using *unobtrusive* javascript (which resides in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js file`):

```
#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<% smart_listing.collection.each do |user| %>
    <%= simple_form_for user, url: user, method: :patch do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :role, required: false, label_html: { class: 'sr-only' }, label: 'Role', selected: user.role %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select.sr-only", function(e){
   $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

This will select the appropriate form for the select to which the function is bound.

I also made it so that you're sending the submit to the `update` action for your `user`. It does not matter which attributes you update each time you send to the `users#update` action, so you can use the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @user.update user_params
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to get rid of the member route you have:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   resources :users
end
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right about the form id issue (as also noted by max). I forgot about that. And thanks for the suggestion regarding the controller action. I tweaked it a bit to use the admin controller, but it works. Unfortunately, I was unable to get the JavaScript working. Nothing happens.

Comment: Try changing the javascript from `select.sr-only` to `.sr-only`